# Hidden condition in the gluing lemma?

Tags: real-analysis

According to the lemma (http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Gluing_lemma_for_open_subsets) by gluing the constant maps $f:(0,1)\to \{1\}$ and $g:(1,2)\to\{2\}$ together we obtain a continuous function $h$ defined by $h(x)=1$ if $x\in (0,1)$ and $h(x)=2$ if $x\in (1,2)$. But clearly $h$ is not continuous. So should we require the intersection of the domains to be nonempty?

**Edit** Of course it is continuous, any open set's preimage is again an open set...

Comment: It's those "clearly" assertions that can really get you.

Answer (score 0):

The function $h : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in the [subspace topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) on $X=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ induced as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Consider an open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}$; there are four possibilities:

1. $\{1,2\} \subset V$
2. $1 \in V$ and $2 \notin V$
3. $1 \notin V$ and $2 \in V$
4. neither 1 nor 2 contained in $V$.

In the first case, the preimage of $V$ under $h$ is all of $X$, hence open. In the second case, the preimage of $V$ under $h$ is $(0,1)$. Note that $(0,1)$ is open in the subspace topology on $X$ as $(0,1)=(0,1) \cap X$ and $(0,1)$ is open in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Case three is similar and in case four the preimage is empty.

I should point out that resulting glued function is always continuous in this sense. Here my proof seems to rely on the fact that the two functions were constant, but this is not the case.